# Rails images in many folders

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I bought ready css and html template. There is many images in many folders, for example:

```
/images/folder_a/folder_a2/folder_a3/image.png
/images/folder_a/folder_s2/folder_s3/image.png
/images/folder_a/folder_b2/folder_b3/image.png
/images/folder_a/folder_z2/folder_z3/image.png
```

Is there some way in rails to do not write path to every image in view?

```
<%= image_tag('image.png') %>
```

gives not_found if I do not write path to it. I know I can copy all files to /images/ ...

Comment: Have you considered using `paperclip` to assign the files to your system?

Comment: paperclip to set path to images??

Comment: Yes sort of - Paperclip to provide a method of storing & accessing the files, so you won't need to individually pick them each time

Comment: Paperclip is *one* way of storing database records for files you or your users have added to the filesystem.  You might be doing something like this already.  Are you?

Answer (score 0):

You could write helpers for each of the major folders to cut down on having to repeat them. If they follow themes this would make sense (ie. icons, header images, borders, buttons etc.)

Answer (score 0):

try these answer `image_tag 'image.png'` or `image_url 'image.png'`

Comment: Please explain your answer to make it more useful for readers.